# ¿Cómo crear un elemento en javascript con una clase o id predefinida?

Tags: javascript, html

Usualmente cuando creas un elemento en javascript el elemento se crea tal cual, sin clase y sin ningún otro atributo. Estoy haciendo este pequeño programa a manera de prueba

```
    <head>
        <style>
            .maso, .carta{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
            }
            .tablero{
                display: flex;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function tomarCarta(){
                var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
                var x = document.createElement("DIV");
                var y = document.createTextNode(a);
                x.appendChild(y);
                document.getElementById("tablero").appendChild(x);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maso" onclick="tomarCarta()">
        </div>
        <div id="tablero" class="tablero">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La función del programa es simplemente repartir cartas con numero aleatorios, todo funciona bien solo que quiero que los `<div>` que son creados tengan un diseño tipo carta, para lo cual necesito que se creen con una clase predeterminada para poder estilizarlos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar `classList` asi:

```html
<head>
        <style>
            .maso, .carta{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
            }
            .tablero{
                display: flex;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function tomarCarta(){
                var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
                var x = document.createElement("DIV");
                var y = document.createTextNode(a);
                x.classList.add("carta");
                x.appendChild(y);
                document.getElementById("tablero").appendChild(x);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maso" onclick="tomarCarta()">
        </div>
        <div id="tablero" class="tablero">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```